# Node Clone operation/tab missing for webform

Tags: nodes, webforms

```
Node Clone 7.x-1.0+2-dev
Webform: 7.x-4.13
Drupal 7
```

I only see the clone operation available on 1 custom content type, and NOT on my webform content type.

I tried installing the node clone tab module, and the tab does not appear either.

Clone any node, clone own node permissions enabled for my role 'Administrator'.

Any suggestions for moving forward?

[image: admin/contentA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides simply enabling the Node Clone module and checking the permissions associated with it, you'll need to select which content types can be cloned.

To do so, go to /admin/config/content/clone
[image: Node Clone Configuration/Admin page for Drupal 7]

After enabling for the "webform" content type, you should see the clone link available near the contextual link / action tabs at the top of a webform page when signed in as an admin and viewing the page.

Comment: PS- the "Clone" action appears as a link and not a tab when just the Node Clone module is installed/enabled.  The supplemental Node Clone Tab module can be used to force the action link to appear with the View/Edit tabs.

Comment: I have followed these directions and it still not does appear on either the find content page as an action.

Comment: To make it appear on the find content page, you will need to override / edit the bulk operations available in the content list view.

Comment: I added a photo of what my admin/content screen shows after following your directions. Are you suggesting I edit a view to change this page?  I am still prone to accept your answer because of the above comment. I made a custom view with a views bulk operation field, added the clone 'action', and it works there. However, why does it not show/work on the default admin/content screen? I have enabled the webform content type, and not disabled it.

Comment: Rather than simply overriding the out-of-the-box admin/content view that comes with Drupal, I'd recommend installing and enabling Administration Views (https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) if you haven't done so already.  Once enabled, you'll want to override the "Administration: Nodes (content)" view to include the node clone action in bulk operations.  This module overrides the system default view, adding a more useful set of search filters (for content managers) to the admin content page.

Comment: For whatever reason, the 'Admin_Views' module, combined with enabling the 'clone' action, solved my problem. However, it did not solve the original issue of why 'clone' was not appearing on my original content page.